# Deep link without using a gallery in Power Apps

Tags: deep-linking, powerapps

Is it possible to deep link from an EditForm instead of a gallery?
Heres my scenario:

1. User is greeted with a home screen with a button that creates a new form and navigates them to the form screen
2. The user presses the button and is sent to the form screen
3. The user fills out the fields that apply to them on the form screen
4. The user presses a submit button that sends an email with a deep link to their boss
5. The boss fills out the rest of the fields with the previous user's fields still filled out
6. The boss submits the form with all the fields (the ones filled out by the previous user and the boss) filled out

As you can see, there is no gallery associated with this app

Please let me know if im not clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved, when the user submits the form and sends the email, a URL should be formed which is sent along with the email from which the other user can navigate directly to the half-filled out form.
The URL can be formed as explained here:
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-deep-linking/
And using the arbitrary key-value pair explained, you can control the navigation and the form can be filtered out based on a unique id you set as a key value pair in the URL being created

Comment: Question about the key-value pair. I do not have ID's of items in my sharepoint list. Would the best solution be to add ID's to my list?

Comment: I suppose each row inserted into Sharepoint should have some unique id to identify the row or if not please add it. Because while the second user accesses the already filled form, it is that id which we use to populate the data into the form.

Comment: I figured out that sharepoint adds a unique ID to every row and I was able to find a way to get that value in power apps. Now in step 4, when the user presses submit, the app attempts to get the id of the previously submitted record (the one the user just filled out) and send that ID with the URL in an email. However, the ID never seems to be loaded when the email is sent. This means the email always has an ID of 0. Do you have any ideas on how I might fix this?

Comment: Try adding the unique id column to the form as a label in PowerApps and check if the value is populated correctly by comparing the value in PowerApps against the Sharepoint list.